# magic data.table that resists subsetting

Tags: r, data.table

A colleague of mine sent over the following `data.table` (version 1.9.4 from CRAN):

```
w <- structure(
  list(
    type = c("current", "prior"),
    value = c(10, 20)
    ), 
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
  index = structure(integer(0), type = c(2L, 1L))
  )
```

At first brush, w seems like a normal `data.table`:

```
> w
      type value
1: current    10
2:   prior    20
> w[type=='prior',]
    type value
1: prior    20
```

But for some reason, it cannot be subset by `type == 'current'`:

```
> w[type=='current',]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: type,value
```

Using the `get` function solves this problem:

```
> w[get('type')=='current',]
      type value
1: current    10
```

As does removing the index from the data.table:

```
x <- structure(
  list(
    type = c("current", "prior"),
    value = c(10, 20)
  ), 
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)
> x
      type value
1: current    10
2:   prior    20
```

What is this "index" attribute on the data.table, and how can I prevent it's creation in the future?  I know my colleague did not intentionally create this index, but somehow during a join or subset operation this data.table acquired that magical property.

Comment: `index` is an internal structure used by `data.table` that's intended to speed up repeated indexing operations. It used to be buggy in 1.9.4, but most of those bugs have been squashed in 1.9.5. It can also be disabled via `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`. Voting to close the question.

Comment: This has been fixed in `data.table` v >= 1.9.5. Voting to close too.

Comment: yes, but +1 for a question with 'magic' in the title ...

Comment: @BenBolker I tried to add the [magic] tag too.